# Facebook login not logging in after log out Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-login, logout

I am building an android application that uses the Facebook SDK. I am currently using the LoginManager to handle the login flow. 
I have already initialised the Facebook sdk in the Applications onCreate method.

```
public class DummyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

I have also setup my LoginActivity as such:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.custom_login_button)
    Button mCustomFacebookButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginManager mLoginManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mLoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    mLoginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mCustomFacebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAuthProgressDialog.show();
            mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this
                    , Arrays.asList("user_events", "email" ,"user_friends"));
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);        
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The flow is that once the login button is pressed, it will start the MainActivity, and in that activity there is a SettingsActivity with a Logout Button that calls
    `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`
which will take you back to the login activity.
The problem that I am facing is that once the logout is called, I can't log back in, and my AccessToken is always null. So in essence I am stuck on the LoginActivity.

It gets weirder, once I delete the build files and reimport the project, it works fine, until I log out again and this problem starts again. It has only been having this problem since I updated to Android Studio 2.1, build tools to 23.0.3, and SDK tools to 25.1.3.

-Edit: its not correcting itself with a re-import anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that in my manifest for my LoginActivity I had noHistory as true. This led to my onActivityResult not being called. Once I removed this line the problem relating to the Facebook login disappeared.